# React re-renders all form controls on every text input change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-state, react-functional-component

I am using react with typescript and functional component and Material UI, I have a large form. Small portion is given below.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Grid, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';

const PublicProfileTest = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<{ town: string; county: string }>({
    town: '',
    county: '',
  });

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setState({ ...state, [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Grid container justify='center' alignItems='center' spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
          <TextField
            variant='outlined'
            fullWidth
            id='town'
            label='Town'
            name='town'
            autoComplete='town'
            placeholder='Town *'
            value={state.town || ''}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container justify='center' alignItems='center' spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
          <TextField
            variant='outlined'
            fullWidth
            id='county'
            label='County'
            name='county'
            autoComplete='county'
            placeholder='County'
            value={state.county || ''}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};

export default PublicProfileTest;
```

I have used React dev tools in chrome to check which dome elements are re-rendering.

When i change the town or county input, the whole component gets updated. It's not a problem here but in a large form that i am building, it degrades the performance.

I expect react to re-render only the changed portion of the dom, why it is updating the whole component.

Any idea and solution to make react re-render the changed component only.

Regards,

Iaq

Comment: One optimization would be to wrap `handleChange` with a `useCallback` hook, which will memoize the callback unless it's dependencies actually changed.

Comment: @MorKadosh I tried your suggestion but it did not work. It rendered both inputs.

Comment: Probably the TextField components are not optimised to render only on prop changes. When you call "setState" you cause the render of the whole component, so React will also render it's children unless they are optimised in some way